# Windows Vista System Restore not working

Tags: windows-vista, 32-bit, system-restore, toshiba-laptop

Vista 32 bit.

System Restore is creating restore points, but when I try to restore my system I get a message saying

> System Restore could not be completed

and my system is returned to its original state.

I have closed/opened System Restore.

`Scannow` reports corrupt files that it cannot repair and I cannot get `Findstr` to run (I am not 100% sure that I am using the correct command). Could System Restore be one of these files?

I have run `chkdsk`. I have run full virus scans with AVG and MBAM, both showed no infection.

The laptop (Toshiba Sat Pro) did not include a start-up disc on purchase and when I queried this I was instructed to make a recovery disc, which I did but I do not have a clue how to use.

Comment: Some symptoms seem to suggest that you HDD might be dieing, thus the data is getting corrupt. I would check your HDD with some tool like `MHDD`.

Comment: Agreed, get HDTune, perform a complete scan and also check SMART status of the drive.